# Is $x*y = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}}$ closed? Injective? Surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, functions

Let $x*y = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}}$.

1. Is $x*y$ closed in $(0, \infty)$?
2. For a given $x > 0$, is the function $f(y) = x*y, (0, \infty) \to (0,\infty)$ injective?
3. For a given $x > 0$, is the function $f(y) = x*y, (0, \infty) \to (0,\infty)$ surjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I tried:

1. Yes.

If $x,y > 0$, then $x*y > 0$.

QED

2. Yes

Let $y_1,y_2 > 0$ s.t. $f(y_1) = f(y_2)$.

Then

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y_1}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y_2}}$$

$$\to \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y_1} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y_2}$$

$$\to \frac{1}{y_1} = \frac{1}{y_2}$$

$$\to y_1 = y_2$$

QED

3. No

Let $a \in \text{codomain}(f) = (0,\infty)$. Suppose $\exists y \in \text{domain}(f) = (0, \infty)$ s.t.

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}} = a$$

$$\to \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{a}$$

$$\to \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{x}$$

$$\to \frac{1}{y} = \frac{x}{xa} - \frac{a}{xa}$$

$$\to \frac{1}{y} = \frac{x-a}{xa}$$

$$\to y = \frac{xa}{x-a}$$

Thus, there is no such $y$ if $a=x$.

QED

Comment: Looks good! Incidentally, note that $x * y$ gives half the harmonic mean of $x$ and $y$, which explains intuitively why it isn't surjective for a fixed $x$.

Comment: @Théophile thanks! ^-^